# Huge amount of session data in /var/sessions

Tags: session, performance, customer-session, php-7, hosting

The website just went down, restarted the server and within a minute it went down again.

I quickly found out the problem was that the disk quota had been exceeded and allowed memory exhausted.

This was due to hundreds of thousands if not millions of `sess_*` files in `var/session` folder.

I tried lots of ways to remove them and this is what worked:

```
find . -name 'sess_*' | xargs rm
```

My Website is now back in good condition and no errors for now but within minutes I can see there are over 500 new session files.

Is this normal?

What should I do to prevent the server going down?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you might have been hit by heavy load potentially. You might not be able to effectively handle a sudden spike without some form of load balancing and auto scaling such as using AWS and multiple servers.

However, alternatively it could just be that it grew to excessive size because nothing is cleaning up the sessions.

I would recommend you consider switching to use Redis as a caching service for sessions. Redis comes with a build in TTL on sessions and as a consequence of this, old sessions would simply drop from the database and stop filling the hard drive with old files.

Official Documentation:

Magento 1: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/using_redis.html

Magento 2: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Redis will also allow to recognize known bots and not creating sessions for them.